# How to call several parallel function in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have several functions in a form creation component that I need to be called at the same time. In fact, each of them are valid values that are allowed values of one of the dropdown form fields. For example, gender, countries, interests, that values come from the server. I subscribed to them in separate functions and now called them in the ngOninit. This works fine, but is there a better way to call multiple functions in parallel?

```
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.gender();
    this.countries();
    this.interests();
  }


  gender() {
      this.apiService.gender().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.gender = res;
     }, error => {
     console.log(error);
     });
    }
  }


  countries() {
      this.apiService.countries().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.countries = res;
    }, error => {
     console.log(error);
     });
  }



  interests() {
      this.apiService.interests().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.countries = res;
      }, error => {
     console.log(error);
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with forkjoin:

```
  ngOnInit() { 
    forkjoin([this.getGender(), this.getCountries(), this.getInterests()]).subscribe();
  }


  getGender() {
      return this.apiService.gender().pipe(tap(gender => (this.gender = gender)));
  }


  getCountries() {
      return this.apiService.countries().pipe(tap(countries => (this.countries = countries)));
  }



  getInterests() {
      return this.apiService.interests().pipe(tap(interests => (this.interests = interests)));
  }
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I handle errors in each function?

Comment: With `forkJoin([]).pipe(catcherror(e => <your code>))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
ngOnInit() { 
   Promise.all([
      this.gender(),
      this.countries(),
      this.interests(),
   ]).then(() => {
      // some code you want to run when all subs return
   });
}

gender(): Promise<void> {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.apiService.gender().subscribe((res: any) => {
          this.gender = res;
          resolve();
      },
          error => { 
             // handle error
          }
      );
   });
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code in `ngOnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() { 
      forkjoin(this.fetchGenders(), this.fetchCountries(), this.fetchInterests()).subscribe(() => {
          //do whatever you want after all calls return
      },
       (err: any) => {
          //generic error handling
           console.log("error", err);
           this.isLoading = false;
       });
    );
}
```

where all your methods will be like (to avoid losing all the chain if any error occurs):

```
public fetchGenders(): Observable<any> {
    this.isLoading = true; //loading indicator for UX purposes - used in html
    const fetchcGendersCallResult = this.http
        .get(...) //your endpoint
        .pipe(
            map((response: any) => response),
            tap(() => this.isLoading = false),
            catchError(...) //error handling for fetching genders
        );
    return fetchcGendersCallResult;
}
```

Please take a look here for more info as well:
https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-error-handling-with-forkjoin-3d4027df70fc